# No consigo darle padding Y con Bootstrap 4 a mi form

Tags: bootstrap-4

tengo el siguiente form:

```
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form col-md-6 py-10 w-50 m-auto bg-info">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label> Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="apellidos">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="usuario">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Repetir contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="re_password" id="re_password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Registrarse</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quisiera darle un poco de **padding-Y** al form, es decir, `paddin-top` y `paddin-bottom`.

He probado en el form, en el div padre del form, pero no me lo hace de ninguna manera.

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Cómo has intentado darle el `padding`? Es decir ¿Qué código has intentado para hacerlo?

Comment: ahi esta, `py-10` en la clase del `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el tipo de `spacing` que estás añadiendo. Según la documentación de Bootstrap:

> Where size is one of:
>
> 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
>   1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
>   2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
>   3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
>   4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
>   5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
>   auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
>
> (You can add more sizes by adding to the $spacers Sass map variable.)

Es decir, los tamaños predefinidos son desde `py-0` a `py-5` . Al estar poniendo `py-10` no lo encuentra ya que Bootstrap no lo tiene predefinido, como bien dice abajo, en caso de querer añadir un estándar a la lista, deberías editar el Sass y añadir el que quieras.

Fuente: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Oh cierto, sabia que tenia un limite pero tenia en la cabeza totalemnte que habia visto que era 10, es decir, de 0-10, muchisimas gracias.